# Got XHR.status 0 while doing http get request through jquery code while HTTP response is 200 ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, jersey

I am trying to send get request to REST based API(JAX-RS/Jersey based API) through jquery. Request reaches successfully to API as  I have seen in logs and on firebug i saw 200 ok response

below is my jquery based client

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://mtnlp.com:8080/restdemo/resources/employee/1',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(xhr){
               alert("error"+xhr.status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But xhr.status is 0.

MY resource is

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getJson( @PathParam("empno") int empno) {  
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    System.out.println("someone calls me");
     switch(empno) {
        case 1 :
          jObject.put("name", "George Koch");
          jObject.put("age", "58");
          break;
      case 2:
          jObject.put("name", "Peter");
          jObject.put("age", "50");
          break;
      default:
          jObject.put("name", "Unknown");
          jObject.put("age", "-1");


  } // end of switch

  return jObject.toString();
}
```

When i use my jersey based client it works fine. but with jquery based client I am facing above issue.

Please find below the request and response headers for HTTP get request

Response Headers

```
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 06:38:12 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Request Headers

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language  en-US,en;q=0.5
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
```

Comment: What HTTP status code is the server actually sending?

Comment: Is the AJAX request coming from a different URL/domain/server?

Comment: Hey Guys !!! Issue has resolved now. After looking into the request headers I have seen the "Origin: null". origin is null because i am trying to run my html directly from file system so it opens with ftp://. Solution is to put the html file into my web app and then open through http://url. it works now.